# Vector Laplace equation with constraint

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, physics, vector-analysis, constraints

I want to solve Laplace equation for a vector $\boldsymbol v=(v_x,v_y)$: $$\nabla^2 \boldsymbol{v}=0$$ but under the constraint that $$(1+v_x)^2+v_y^2=1$$
which becomes $v_y = -(2v_x+v_x^2)^{1/2}$.

My boundary conditions are:

$$\lim_{r\rightarrow\infty} v(x,y)=0$$
$$v(r=a,\theta)=( \cos(\theta/2), \sin(\theta/2) )$$

Normally, without the constraints, I would have

$$\boldsymbol v = \frac{a^{1/2}}{r^{1/2}} ( \cos(\theta/2), \sin(\theta/2) )$$

But how could I use Lagrange multipliers in this situation, if I want to impose the condition $|\boldsymbol{\hat{x}}+\boldsymbol{v}|=1$? Are there any other straightforward methods?

Comment: Would it make sense to consider a system of two Lagrangians, one for each component of $\boldsymbol{v}$?

Comment: You conditions is not contradict each other. $(\cos(\theta/2)+1)^2+\sin(\theta/2)^2=1+2\cos(\theta/2)$